# javascript filter by object key and return value of nested object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I want to return the value of a key for one of the elements inside the object using a condition:

```
const raw = {
  item1: { name: 'sdfd1', otherStuff: { book:'sdfd11' } },
  item2: { name: 'sdfd2', otherStuff: { book:'sdfd22' } },
  item3: { name: 'sdfd3', otherStuff: { book:'sdfd33' } }
};


var anotherOne = {
  country1 : { city: 'one', item: 'item3'},
  country2 : { city: 'two', item: 'item4'}
}

var searchTerm = anotherOne.country1.item; // item3
var secondTerm = someUser.otherInfo // 'otherStuff'
var result = Object.keys(raw)
  .filter(key => { 
  if (key === searchTerm){
   return raw[searchTerm][secondTerm].book
  }})

  console.log('result:' result); // sdfd33
```

Basically, i want to look for the `searchTerm` in the keys of the object `raw`, and return the value for the `book` key. In this example, it should return `sdfd33`.
My attempt is returning nothing.

### updated:

updated the question.

Comment: `key` is just a string, return `raw[key].book`

Comment: `raw[searchTerm].book` is what you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use square bracket `[]` while accessing a object key through a variable.
Hopefully the `filter` & `Object.keys` will not be required in this case

```js
const raw = {
  item1: {
    name: 'sdfd1',
    book: 'sdfd11'
  },
  item2: {
    name: 'sdfd2',
    book: 'sdfd22'
  },
  item3: {
    name: 'sdfd3',
    book: 'sdfd33'
  }
};

var searchTerm = 'item3';
//using square bracket when acceing key using variable
var result = raw[searchTerm].book
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return the value like :

```
var result = raw.item3.book;

console.log(result);
```

result should be sdfd33